# TypeError: create_int(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported: , and more problems about virtual keyboard

Tags: python, virtual-keyboard

Trying virtual keyboard but this happen :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bi\OneDrive\Documents\src\xd.py", line 46, in <module>
    tracker = HandTracker(detectionCon=0.8)
  File "C:\Users\bi\OneDrive\Documents\src\handTracker.py", line 14, in __init__
    self.hands = self.mpHands.Hands(self.mode, self.maxHands, self.detectionCon, self.trackCon)
  File "C:\Users\bi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\mediapipe\python\solutions\hands.py", line 114, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\Users\bi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\mediapipe\python\solution_base.py", line 258, in __init__
    self._input_side_packets = {
  File "C:\Users\bi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\mediapipe\python\solution_base.py", line 259, in <dictcomp>
    name: self._make_packet(self._side_input_type_info[name], data)
  File "C:\Users\bi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\mediapipe\python\solution_base.py", line 513, in _make_packet
    return getattr(packet_creator, 'create_' + packet_data_type.value)(data)
TypeError: create_int(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. (arg0: int) -> mediapipe.python._framework_bindings.packet.Packet
```

Nevermind the name xd because it is just a name for the virtual keyboard
, here is my code :

```
import cv2
import numpy as np 
import time
from keys import *
from handTracker import *
from pynput.keyboard import Controller

def getMousPos(event , x, y, flags, param):
    global clickedX, clickedY
    global mouseX, mouseY
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        #print(x,y)
        clickedX, clickedY = x, y
    if event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
    #     print(x,y)
        mouseX, mouseY = x, y

def calculateIntDidtance(pt1, pt2):
    return int(((pt1[0]-pt2[0])**2 + (pt1[1]-pt2[1])**2)**0.5)

# Creating keys
w,h = 80, 60
startX, startY = 40, 200
keys=[]
letters =list("QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM")
for i,l in enumerate(letters):
    if i<10:
        keys.append(Key(startX + i*w + i*5, startY, w, h, l))
    elif i<19:
        keys.append(Key(startX + (i-10)*w + i*5, startY + h + 5,w,h,l))  
    else:
        keys.append(Key(startX + (i-19)*w + i*5, startY + 2*h + 10, w, h, l)) 

keys.append(Key(startX+25, startY+3*h+15, 5*w, h, "Space"))
keys.append(Key(startX+8*w + 50, startY+2*h+10, w, h, "clr"))
keys.append(Key(startX+5*w+30, startY+3*h+15, 5*w, h, "<--"))

showKey = Key(300,5,80,50, 'Show')
exitKey = Key(300,65,80,50, 'Exit')
textBox = Key(startX, startY-h-5, 10*w+9*5, h,'')

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
ptime = 0

# initiating the hand tracker
tracker = HandTracker(detectionCon=0.8)

# getting frame's height and width
frameHeight, frameWidth, _ = cap.read()[1].shape
showKey.x = int(frameWidth*1.5) - 85
exitKey.x = int(frameWidth*1.5) - 85
#print(showKey.x)

clickedX, clickedY = 0, 0
mousX, mousY = 0, 0

show = False
cv2.namedWindow('video')
counter = 0
previousClick = 0

keyboard = Controller()
while True:
    if counter >0:
        counter -=1
        
    signTipX = 0
    signTipY = 0

    thumbTipX = 0
    thumbTipY = 0

    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        break
    frame = cv2.resize(frame,(int(frameWidth*1.5), int(frameHeight*1.5)))
    frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
    #find hands
    frame = tracker.findHands(frame)
    lmList = tracker.getPostion(frame, draw=False)
    if lmList:
        signTipX, signTipY = lmList[8][1], lmList[8][2]
        thumbTipX, thumbTipY = lmList[4][1], lmList[4][2]
        if calculateIntDidtance((signTipX, signTipY), (thumbTipX, thumbTipY)) <50:
            centerX = int((signTipX+thumbTipX)/2)
            centerY = int((signTipY + thumbTipY)/2)
            cv2.line(frame, (signTipX, signTipY), (thumbTipX, thumbTipY), (0,255,0),2)
            cv2.circle(frame, (centerX, centerY), 5, (0,255,0), cv2.FILLED)

    ctime = time.time()
    fps = int(1/(ctime-ptime))

    cv2.putText(frame,str(fps) + " FPS", (10,20), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.8, (0,0,0),2)
    showKey.drawKey(frame,(255,255,255), (0,0,0),0.1, fontScale=0.5)
    exitKey.drawKey(frame,(255,255,255), (0,0,0),0.1, fontScale=0.5)
    cv2.setMouseCallback('video', getMousPos)

    if showKey.isOver(clickedX, clickedY):
        show = not show
        showKey.text = "Hide" if show else "Show"
        clickedX, clickedY = 0, 0

    if exitKey.isOver(clickedX, clickedY):
        #break
        exit()

    #checking if sign finger is over a key and if click happens
    alpha = 0.5
    if show:
        textBox.drawKey(frame, (255,255,255), (0,0,0), 0.3)
        for k in keys:
            if k.isOver(mouseX, mouseY) or k.isOver(signTipX, signTipY):
                alpha = 0.1
                # writing using mouse right click
                if k.isOver(clickedX, clickedY):                              
                    if k.text == '<--':
                        textBox.text = textBox.text[:-1]
                    elif k.text == 'clr':
                        textBox.text = ''
                    elif len(textBox.text) < 30:
                        if k.text == 'Space':
                            textBox.text += " "
                        else:
                            textBox.text += k.text
                            
                # writing using fingers
                if (k.isOver(thumbTipX, thumbTipY)):
                    clickTime = time.time()
                    if clickTime - previousClick > 0.4:                               
                        if k.text == '<--':
                            textBox.text = textBox.text[:-1]
                        elif k.text == 'clr':
                            textBox.text = ''
                        elif len(textBox.text) < 30:
                            if k.text == 'Space':
                                textBox.text += " "
                            else:
                                textBox.text += k.text
                                #simulating the press of actuall keyboard
                                keyboard.press(k.text)
                        previousClick = clickTime
            k.drawKey(frame,(255,255,255), (0,0,0), alpha=alpha)
            alpha = 0.5
        clickedX, clickedY = 0, 0        
    ptime = ctime
    cv2.imshow('video', frame)

    ## stop the video when 'q' is pressed
    pressedKey = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if pressedKey == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Any ideas to this code ? I have imported all the library that is needed for the project. I am using Python 3.10.1, numpy 1.22.0, opencv-python 4.5.5.62, oh and here is the library of keys and handTracker that are imported :
keys :

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

class Key():

    def __init__(self,x,y,w,h,text):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.w = w
        self.h = h
        self.text=text
    
    def drawKey(self, img, text_color=(255,255,255), bg_color=(0,0,0),alpha=0.5, fontFace=cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, fontScale=0.8, thickness=2):
        
        #draw the box
        bg_rec = img[self.y : self.y + self.h, self.x : self.x + self.w]
        white_rect = np.ones(bg_rec.shape, dtype=np.uint8) #* 25
        white_rect[:] = bg_color
        res = cv2.addWeighted(bg_rec, alpha, white_rect, 1-alpha, 1.0)
        
        # Putting the image back to its position
        img[self.y : self.y + self.h, self.x : self.x + self.w] = res

        #put the letter
        tetx_size = cv2.getTextSize(self.text, fontFace, fontScale, thickness)
        text_pos = (int(self.x + self.w/2 - tetx_size[0][0]/2), int(self.y + self.h/2 + tetx_size[0][1]/2))
        cv2.putText(img, self.text,text_pos , fontFace, fontScale,text_color, thickness)

    def isOver(self,x,y):
        if (self.x + self.w > x > self.x) and (self.y + self.h> y >self.y):
            return True
        return False
```

handTracker :

```
import mediapipe as mp
import numpy as np
import cv2


class HandTracker():
    def __init__(self, mode=False, maxHands=2, detectionCon=0.5, trackCon=0.5):
        self.mode = mode
        self.maxHands = maxHands
        self.detectionCon = detectionCon
        self.trackCon = trackCon

        self.mpHands = mp.solutions.hands
        self.hands = self.mpHands.Hands(self.mode, self.maxHands, self.detectionCon, self.trackCon)
        self.mpDraw = mp.solutions.drawing_utils

    def findHands(self, img, draw=True):
        imgRGB = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        self.results = self.hands.process(imgRGB)

        if self.results.multi_hand_landmarks:
            for handLm in self.results.multi_hand_landmarks:
                if draw:
                    self.mpDraw.draw_landmarks(img, handLm, self.mpHands.HAND_CONNECTIONS)
        return img

    def getPostion(self, img, handNo = 0, draw=True):
        lmList =[]
        if self.results.multi_hand_landmarks:
            myHand = self.results.multi_hand_landmarks[handNo]
            for id, lm in enumerate(myHand.landmark):
                h, w, c = img.shape
                cx, cy = int(lm.x*w), int(lm.y*h)
                lmList.append([id, cx, cy])

                if draw:
                    cv2.circle(img, (cx, cy), 5, (255,0,255), cv2.FILLED)
        return lmList
```

Oh and my mediapipe version is the latest version.
I am using sublime text for writing the code and command prompt to run the code.
I hope that those information are enough. So what should I do and what should I fix ? (Note : I can't download pycharm or anacoda prompt because I somehow glitched in my computer. Thanks)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).